# Jquery Image Rotator with iPhone-like Page dots

Tags: jquery, iphone, rotator

I need a jQuery Image Rotator that rotates 4 images (fades in/out every 5 seconds or so), but it has the iPhone page dots to show which one is currently shown ([Example of Dots](http://cld.ly/323t6)). How would you do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery Tools scrollable:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/index.html

You could set up the container to only show one image a time instead of five, and use the navi plugin. Or roll your own, all you'd really need to do is match the index of the image shown to the index of a list item and assign an "active" class....

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) for this with small modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think any rotator with navigation could be easily made to look like this (replace the navigation text with bullets or images) such as:

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#demo

(scroll down and click "Image Slider - External Controls" on the right navigation column for an example)

Another option may be the offerings that http://jqtouch.com/ provides.